# Classifying non-MNIST image after learning MNIST

Tags: python, image, machine-learning, classification, mnist

My machine learning algorithm has already learned the 70000 images in the MNIST database. I want to test it on an image not included in the MNIST dataset. However, my predict function cannot read the array representation of my test image.

How do I test my algorithm on an external image? 
Why is my code failing?

PS I'm using python3

**Error Received:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "hello_world2.py", line 28, in <module>
    print(sgd_clf.predict(arr))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/linear_model/base.py", line 336, in predict
    scores = self.decision_function(X)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/linear_model/base.py", line 317, in decision_function
    % (X.shape[1], n_features))
ValueError: X has 15 features per sample; expecting 784
```

**Code:**

```
# Common Imports
import numpy as np
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_mldata
from sklearn.linear_model import SGDClassifier
from PIL import Image
from resizeimage import resizeimage   

# loading and learning MNIST data
mnist = fetch_mldata('MNIST original')
x, y = mnist["data"], mnist["target"]
sgd_clf = SGDClassifier(random_state=42)
sgd_clf.fit(x, y)

# loading and converting to array a non-MNIST image of a "5", which is in the same folder
img = Image.open("5.png")
arr = np.array(img)

# trying to predict that the image is a "5"
img = Image.open("5.png")   
img = img.convert('L') #makes it greyscale
img = resizeimage.resize_thumbnail(img, [28,28])
arr = np.array(img)

print(sgd_clf.predict(arr)) # ERROR... why????????? How do you fix it?????
```

Comment: That image will have to be resized. The MNIST images are 28x28.

Comment: Also your image seems to be 3-channelled. You'll have to grayscale it.

Comment: How do you resize a MNIST image? (Note: see original code for edits. Thank you.)

Comment: This example might be helpful: https://github.com/niektemme/tensorflow-mnist-predict/blob/master/predict_2.py

Answer (score 2):

It's not simply a matter of resizing, the image needs the digit centered and white on black etc.  I've been working on a function to this job.  This is the current version that uses opencv, although it could do with further improvement, including using PIL instead of opencv, but it should give an idea of the steps required.

```
def open_as_mnist(image_path):
    """
    Assume this is a color or grey scale image of a digit which has not so far been preprocessed

    Black and White
    Resize to 20 x 20 (digit in center ideally)
    Sharpen
    Add white border to make it 28 x 28
    Convert to white on black
    """
    # open as greyscale
    image = cv2.imread(image_path, 0)

    # crop to contour with largest area
    cropped = do_cropping(image)

    # resizing the image to 20 x 20
    resized20 = cv2.resize(cropped, (20, 20), interpolation=cv2.INTER_CUBIC)

    cv2.imwrite('1_resized.jpg', resized20)

    # gaussian filtering
    blurred = cv2.GaussianBlur(resized20, (3, 3), 0)

    # white digit on black background
    ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(blurred, 127, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)

    padded = to20by20(thresh)


    resized28 = padded_image(padded, 28)

    # normalize the image values to fit in the range [0,1]
    norm_image = np.asarray(resized28, dtype=np.float32) / 255.

    # cv2.imshow('image', norm_image)
    # cv2.waitKey(0)

    # # Flatten the image to a 1-D vector and return
    flat = norm_image.reshape(1, 28 * 28)
    # return flat

    # normalize pixels to 0 and 1. 0 is pure white, 1 is pure black.
    tva = [(255 - x) * 1.0 / 255.0 for x in flat]
    return tva



def padded_image(image, tosize):
    """
    This method adds padding to the image and makes it to a tosize x tosize array,
    without losing the aspect ratio.
    Assumes desired image is square

    :param image: the input image as numpy array
    :param tosize: the final dimensions
    """

    # image dimensions
    image_height, image_width = image.shape


    # if not already square then pad to square
    if image_height != image_width:

        # Add padding
        # The aim is to make an image of different width and height to a sqaure image
        # For that first the biggest attribute among width and height are determined.
        max_index = np.argmax([image_height, image_width])


        # if height is the biggest one, then add padding to width until width becomes
        # equal to height
        if max_index == 0:
            #order of padding is: top, bottom, left, right
            left = int((image_height - image_width) / 2)
            right = image_height - image_width - left
            padded_img = cv2.copyMakeBorder(image, 0, 0,
                                            left,
                                            right,
                                            cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT)

        # else if width is the biggest one, then add padding to height until height becomes
        # equal to width
        else:
            top = int((image_width - image_height) / 2)
            bottom = image_width - image_height - top
            padded_img = cv2.copyMakeBorder(image, top, bottom, 0, 0,  cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT)
    else:
        padded_img = image


    # now that it's a square, add any additional padding required
    image_height, image_width = padded_img.shape
    padding = tosize - image_height

    # need to handle where padding is not divisiable by 2
    left = top = int(padding/2)
    right = bottom = padding - left
    resized = cv2.copyMakeBorder(image, top, bottom, left, right, cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT)


    return resized
```

Comment: Please post a working example. This is giving errors.

Comment: I think `do_cropping` function is missing here?

Answer (score 1):

Please try this:

```
img = Image.open("5.png")
img = img.resize((28,28))
img = img.convert('L') #makes it greyscale
```

Comment: Tried it. Made progress. But I still need to resize the image. I'm confused on how to resize a MNIST image. (Note: please see code above for recent improvements. Thank you.)

Comment: I updated my answer. Maybe it because you resize the image after converting it to gray, so it's added 3 layers again to the image. And you don't need to use another library for just resizing.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to read a picture then resize it, please try

```
In [1]: import PIL.Image as Image

In [2]: img = Image.open('2.jpg', mode='r')

In [3]: img.mode
Out[3]: 'RGB'

In [4]: img.size
Out[4]: (2880, 1800)

In [5]: img_new = img.resize([4000, 4000], Image.ANTIALIAS)

In [6]: img_new2 = img.resize([32, 32], Image.ANTIALIAS)
```

Docs are [here](http://omz-software.com/pythonista/docs/ios/Image.html)

This is the 2.jpg, sorry, it is not a digit.

[image]
*This picture is from the Internet, sorry, I forget the source.*

If you encounter the mode is 'RGBA', I recommend you transfer it to 'RGB' mode,

```
newimg = Image.new('RGB', img.size)
newimg.paste(img, mask=img.split()[3])
return newimg
```